# Using a list as a value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that I want to insert in a dataframe. The data is `columns= ['Title', 'Category']`. For each Titles I have one or more Categories, and I decided to insert the categories as a list. So my df looks like this:

```
In [39]: title_cat_df
Out[39]: 
    Title      Category
0  Title1  [Cat1, Cat2]
1  Title3        [Cat5]
2  Title2  [Cat3, Cat4]
...
...
...
```

However I don't know if this is a pythonic/pandaionic(?!) approach, since I have stumbled upon problems such as looking for specific categories using `isin`:

```
In [41]: test_df['Category'].isin(cat_list)
Out[41]: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What would be a better way to represent categories in this case, and hopefully be able to look for titles in a specific category or categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to `set`s and use `&` for intersection with list converted to `set` also:

```
cat_list = ['Cat1','Cat2', 'Cat4']
print (test_df['Category'].apply(set) & set(cat_list))
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Category, dtype: bool
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
test_df = test_df[test_df['Category'].apply(set) & set(cat_list)]
print (test_df)
    Title      Category
0  Title1  [Cat1, Cat2]
2  Title2  [Cat3, Cat4]
```

Comment: This works great with my current approach. I have also tested it with my main dataframe of 5million rows. It did freeze my laptop for a few minutes but it came through in the end, so thanks. However from what I gathered using a list inside a dataframe isn't very idiomatic, but what else can be done when there isn't a specific number of categories, for each entry?

Comment: Yes, I agree, if use `lists` or `set`s it is not native format in pandas. Only solution for this should be create scalars from lists, but disadvantage is huger DataFrame, e.g. from sample with 3 rows get 5 :(